# SQL Server 2008 - insert into table with select script and a hardcoded value

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, insert-into

I want to insert into a table the following information:

```
Week                          NoTrans     Spend
02.01.12-08.01.12             11          520
```

The script I have is:

```
DECLARE @Week VARCHAR(22)
DECLARE @Date1 DATETIME
DECLARE @Date2 DATETIME
DECLARE @Script VARCHAR(8000)
SET @date1 = '02 Jan 2012'
SET @date2 = '08 Jan 2012'
SET @Week = Convert(varchar(12), @date1, 104)+'-'+Convert(varchar(12), @date2, 104)

PRINT @Week

SET @Script = 'INSERT INTO table2 (WEEK, NoTrans, Spend)
SELECT '+ @WEEK +', Transactions, Spend
FROM table1 (NOLOCK)


EXEC @Script
```

The `Week` column comes from `@Week` not table1.

I'm getting the following error message:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 20
>   The name 'INSERT INTO table2 (WEEK, Transactions, Spend)
>   SELECT 02.01.2012-08.01.2012, Transactions, Spend
>   FROM table1 (NOLOCK)' is not a valid identifier.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the last line to:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @Script
```

Or alternatively, don't bother with creating @Script and using EXEC, just run the query like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (WEEK, NoTrans, Spend)
SELECT @WEEK, Transactions, Spend
FROM table1 (NOLOCK)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use `EXECUTE` for executing dynamic SQL you need to use parenthesis:

```
 EXEC(@Script)
```

Also you can use `sp_executesql` as suggested in another answer (it has the advantage that allows parametrized queries).

Also, I think that you need to quote the string for WEEK:

```
SET @Script = 'INSERT INTO table2 (WEEK, NoTrans, Spend)
SELECT '''+ @WEEK +''', Transactions, Spend
FROM table1'
```

PS: Make sure that you understand what implies using NOLOCK:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2009/04/06/sql-server-nolock-hint-other-poor-ideas.aspx

Comment: This answer is better than mine... :)  And yes the quoting is necessary too, I didn't spot that